# Install tensorflow-serving-api using pip without automatically updating tensorflow

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, pip, upgrade

I have tensorflow version 1.4.1 I want to install tensorflow-serving-api with pip. But when I install it it automatically update my tensorflow to a most recent version. How Can I install tensorflow-serving-api with pip without updating my tensorflow? Probably a similar question has been asked several times but I didn't find a similar one. I accept as an answer if you point me to that similar question. Thank you.

Comment: A possible workaround is to just uninstall the new tensorflow and then install the previous version. Tensorflow-serving-api works. This worked for me but I still would like to know how to do it as it is supposed to be done.

Comment: Or you could just install a version that matches your desired version of `tensorflow`: `$ pip install "tensoflow-serving-api<1.5"`.

Comment: Another workaround is to download the tensorflow serving API pyPI module and extract the libraries. It worked for me.